# Any way to make an image to go size %300 if a button is pressed? / Fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, zooming

I use this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/TngqB.jpg  but as you can see the text it's not very visible, so I need to zoom it. I borrowed an flip book effect to create my page, and i wonder if I can create a button when it's pressed to make the page to size 300+  and when it's pressed again to go back.

I have this demo http://www.vestigedayz.com/Lucius-Payne/ro/Capitolul1/Indisponibil/    (as you can see at page 2 you can't see the text at all)

**My HTML :**

```
<div class="flipbook-viewport">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flipbook">
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/1.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/2.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/3.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/4.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/5.jpg)"></div>
            <div style="background-image:url(pages/6.jpg)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS :**

```css
.flipbook-viewport{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.flipbook-viewport .container{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:auto;
}

.flipbook-viewport .flipbook{
    width:922px;
    height:600px;
    left:-461px;
    top:-300px;
}

.flipbook-viewport .page{
    width:461px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:white;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}

.flipbook .page{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -ms-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flipbook-viewport .page img{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Use JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Maybe a [jQuery zoom plugin](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples)?

Comment: @VDWWD that can work. I'm trying it. Thanks But the thing is that my images are uploaded by  <div style="background-image:url(pages/1.jpg)"></div>  and  jquery's  is by   <img id="zoom_01" src="small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"/>

Answer (score 1):

You could use a button with a javascript onclick handler which sets a css-class.
Then you could use css3 scale-attribute if the set class is present.